# CAAnimation to animate a checkmark drawing

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation

I am trying to make a simple check mark control, which consists of just a square and a checkmark in it. I would like to animate drawing and erasing of the check mark when the control is tapped. This is what I have so far:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: checkBox.size * 2 / 3))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: checkBox.size / 3, y: checkBox.size))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: checkBox.size, y: 0))

pathLayer.frame = checkBox.bounds
pathLayer.path = path.cgPath
pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red().cgColor
pathLayer.fillColor = nil
pathLayer.lineWidth = checkMarkWidth
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel

let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"strokeEnd")
pathAnimation.duration = checkMarkAnimationDuration
pathAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0)
pathAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1)

let reverseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"strokeEnd")
reverseAnimation.duration = checkMarkAnimationDuration
reverseAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1)
reverseAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0)
reverseAnimation.delegate = self
```

Then I start the animations like this:

```
var on: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if on {
            checkBox.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
            pathLayer.removeAllAnimations()
            pathLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey:"strokeEnd")
        } else {
            pathLayer.removeAllAnimations()
            pathLayer.add(reverseAnimation, forKey:"strokeEnd")
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in my CAAnimationDelegate I do this:

```
public func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    pathLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
}
```

This looks good, except that when I test it on the real device there is a little flash when the reversed animation is done, but before the layer is removed. It seems I am missing an `animationWillStop` callback.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this glitch?

Also any other suggestions on how to improve this code are welcome, cause I'm completely new to Core Animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Core Animation has three layer tree, one is **model layer tree**, which you mostly interact with. one is **presentation layer tree**, which contains in-flight running animation values. and the last one is **render layer tree**, which actually render layer and private to Core Animation.

CAAnimation Only change value on CALayer's presentationLayer. after animation end, the animation is removed and strokeEnd **jump back** to your modal layer's value: 1.0. This is why you have flash.

so, you can change

```
var on: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if on {
            checkBox.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
            pathLayer.removeAllAnimations()
            pathLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey:"strokeEnd")
        } else {
            pathLayer.removeAllAnimations()
            pathLayer.add(reverseAnimation, forKey:"strokeEnd")
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
var on: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if on {
            checkBox.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
            pathLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0 // set property to final state
            pathLayer.removeAllAnimations()
            pathLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey:"strokeEnd")
        } else {
            pathLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0 // set property to final state
            pathLayer.removeAllAnimations()
            pathLayer.add(reverseAnimation, forKey:"strokeEnd")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement these steps:

**Step1:**

- Create an xcode project with name **CheckMarkAnimation**.
  In your interface builder add an UIImageView with image "**checkmark.png**".

**Step2:**

- I have just written the code snippets below.

**#import < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>**

```
#define RectWidth(f)                         f.size.width

#define RectHeight(f)                       f.size.height

- (void)doMaskAnimationOnCheckMarck:(UIImageView*)imgView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay alpha:(CGFloat)alpha{ 
   
 UIBezierPath * fromPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 1,RectHeight(imgView.bounds))];
 UIBezierPath * toPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imgView.bounds];
  CAShapeLayer * maaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maaskLayer.path = toPath.CGPath;
    maaskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:alpha].CGColor;
 imgView.layer.mask = maskLayer; 
  CABasicAnimation * animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];    animation.keyPath = @"path";
 animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + delay;
 animation.fromValue = (__bridge id)fromPath.CGPath;    animation.toValue = (__bridge id)toPath.CGPath;
 animation.duration = duration;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
 animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
 animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
 [maaskLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"MaskAnimation"];
}
```

You should have better luck using this link as follows.

[How to animate a checkmark Using Bezier path as Clipping Mask  in iOS](https://www.huntmyideas.com/blogs/how-to-animate-a-checkmark-using-bezier-path-as-clipping-mask-in-ios)

Hope it will help.